# how do I resolve this flutter XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: flutter, postdata

i tried to run a simple post request using flutter but i got redirected to this code
the second code that starts with class is my actual code, i will be grateful if you can help me out

`

```
 
 unawaited(xhr.onLoad.first.then((_) {
      var body = (xhr.response as ByteBuffer).asUint8List();
      completer.complete(StreamedResponse(
          ByteStream.fromBytes(body), xhr.status!,
          contentLength: body.length,
          request: request,
          headers: xhr.responseHeaders,
          reasonPhrase: xhr.statusText));
    }));


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  postData() async {
   const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        body: {'id': 1.toString(), 'name': 'paul', 'email': 'paul@gmail.com'});

    print(response.body);
  }






  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Post Data '),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Center(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'type your message '),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter a valid message ';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onChanged: () {
                  setState(() {
                    
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    
                      // Perform registration logic here
                      postData();

                      
                    
                  },
                  child: const Text("submit"))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
 }
```

`

i checked the documentation to see wether their is a package i missed but known

i checked flutter_cors but still got the same issues
i checked the documentation to see wether their is a package i missed but known

i checked flutter_cors but still got the same issues
i checked the documentation to see wether their is a package i missed but known

i checked flutter_cors but still got the same issues

i checked the documentation to see wether their is a package i missed but known

i checked flutter_cors but still got the same issues